# Thoughts on implementation of weakly typed web service

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

Not really sure if the title is the best describing title but anyways;

I'm doing some integration against an external system which offers some wcf services with a total of more than 300 methods. Each method takes an api key parameter and a xml string parameter.

I'm looking for some nice clean design on how to approach the xml string parameters.
Some of the methods have optional xml parameters, nested parameters and list elements.

Example: 
        EntityManager.PerformCommand

```
    <PARAMETERS>
        <COMMANDID>Commands.ReadStatus</COMMANDID>
        <ENTITYID>ID of the entity</ENTITY> (optional - for single entity)
        <ENTITIES>
            <ENTITY>
               <ID>ID of entity #1</ID>
             </ENTITY>
             <ENTITY>
               <ID>ID of entity #n</ID>
            </ENTITY>
        </ENTITIES> (optional - use for multiple entities)
        <TIMEOUTDATETIME>2014-01-01 00:00:00.000</TIMEOUTDATETIME>
    </PARAMETERS>
```

While a different command could use some other parameters and syntax documented by the provider of this service.

So to my actual question; what would be a nice design for this?

I'd like to create a command queue processor and result processor working between the db and the external system and have my own implementation between UI and database.
But I don't have any good ideas on how to have the dynamic build from the UI and some validation on the XML before sending it to the external system.

As for now, I'ved typed the different XML parameters into strings with String.Format where I've passed my parameters. I also tested a fluent interface where I removed unpopulated elements, but it seems kind of tedious way of achiving what I want.

(Note below code is just for testing)

```
public class ParameterHelper
{
    private StringBuilder parameters = new StringBuilder();

    public ParameterHelper Initialize()
    {
        parameters.Clear();
        parameters.Append("<PARAMETERS>");
        return this;
    }

    public ParameterHelper NewLevel(string levelName)
    {
        parameters.AppendFormat("<{0}>", levelName.ToUpper());
        return this;
    }
    public ParameterHelper CloseLevel(string levelName)
    {
        parameters.AppendFormat("</{0}>", levelName.ToUpper());
        return this;
    }

    public ParameterHelper WithParameter(string parameterName, object parameterValue)
    {
        parameters.AppendFormat("<{0}>{1}</{0}>", parameterName.ToUpper(), parameterValue);
        return this;
    }

    public ParameterHelper List(string parameterName, IEnumerable<string> parameterValues)
    {
        foreach (string parameterValue in parameterValues)
        {
            parameters.AppendFormat("<{0}>{1}</{0}>", parameterName.ToUpper(), parameterValue);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public ParameterHelper Object(string stringParameterFormat, params object[] args )
    {

        parameters.AppendFormat(stringParameterFormat.ToUpper(), args);

        return this;
    }

    public ParameterHelper ObjectList(string outerParameterName, string innerParameterName, IEnumerable<string> parameterValues)
    {
        foreach (string parameterValue in parameterValues)
        {
            parameters.AppendFormat("<{0}><{1}>{2}</{1}></{0}>", outerParameterName.ToUpper(), innerParameterName.ToUpper(), parameterValue);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public ParameterHelper ParameterObject(List<ParameterObject> parameterObjects )
    {
        foreach (ParameterObject po in parameterObjects)
        {
            parameters.AppendFormat(po.ParameterStringFormat.ToUpper(), po.StringParameters.ToArray());
        }

        return this;
    }

    public string GetParameters()
    {
        parameters.Append("</PARAMETERS>");
        var xDoc = XElement.Parse(parameters.ToString());
        xDoc.Descendants().Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Value)).Remove();
        return xDoc.ToString();
    }

}
```

So this is me reaching out for someone with more experince than me.

Thank you.

Comment: Initially I would simply create a class that encapsulates the schema of each XML fragment you could send to the server, or does the server take the same schema for every method? A fluent interface isn't necessary IMO. I would also separate the class from the thing responsible for building the resulting XML. I would then attempt to create an adapter over that service to talk to such that I could work against strongly-typed items as opposed to XML strings.

Comment: Thank you for your input!
In the past i created classes for each method, but some of the method parameters have 30+ optional parameters (such as list retrieval where you can use many different parameters for restricting your search criteria) which was very tideous to create in order to make them serializable.

Comment: That is still the route I would do, but try perhaps to use T4 Templates based on the XML schema? There is actually a class generation tool that can generate classes from XML itself. I wouldn't use the XML serialization attributes, I would favour creating a writer class manually. You could make it general and use reflection.

Comment: The external system have some common xml elements between the different methods, but in general there are different schemas. Do you mean you'd create classes for each method and create an object and populate the required fields and write it to xml before sending it?

Comment: If there are commonalities I would push those into a base class. But yes, generally speaking I would first attempt this route. You could encapsulate a lot of common repeating code into factory classes that can build these objects and only accept parameters for the one or two arguments that change. There are loads of ways to reduce the "wordiness" of this approach.